# Can I adjust knobs in Simulink more accurately?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to adjust knobs by inputting the value I actually want, somehow, rather than moving the dial manually. Moving the dial can be very inaccurate, I don't get round numbers or the precise value I want, just a rational number with way too many decimals.

[image: See here]

Is there any way to round the result without using the Rounding Function block? Can I input the value of the knob directly?

Comment: A knob is an alternative to the standard for people who don't care about exact numerical value. Standard is having a box with constant values. Use the standard!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use a `Constant` block instead of a knob? That's literally the block to "input the value directly". Maybe add a switch block or something so if the constant is 0 (or some other value) then the value is taken from the knob, otherwise the constant value is used.

For example:

[image: example]